# How do I increase the score every time the user gets a question correct?

Tags: python

I'm making a very simple math quiz game and I want to increase the score every time the user gets a question correct. But when I run the code, the score stays at 1 and doesn't increase.

```
import random
for x in range (0,10):
   num_1 = random.randint(1,10)
   num_2 = random.randint(1,10)
   ansstring = "What is {0} + {1}:".format(num_1,num_2)
   answer = int(input(ansstring))
   score = 0
if answer == (num_1 + num_2):
   print("CORRECT!")
   score = score + 1
   print ("Score:",score)
else:
   print("INCORRECT! Correct answer is", (num_1 + num_2))
   
print ("Your score was", score,"/10")
```

Comment: Take the score variable out of the for loop

Comment: Also, put the `if-else` conditions inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put all the game play inside the `for loop`, and put the variable `score` outside of the `for` loop.

The reason why would be because everytime the `for loop` iterates, you are resetting the variable.

For the same reason, you need to check each sum, so you would need to put the `if` statements inside the `for loop`.

Code:

```py
import random
score = 0
for x in range (0,10):
    num_1 = random.randint(1,10)
    num_2 = random.randint(1,10)
    ansstring = "What is {0} + {1}:".format(num_1,num_2) + " "
    answer = int(input(ansstring))
    if answer == (num_1 + num_2):
        print("CORRECT!")
        score = score + 1
        print ("Score:",score)
    else:
        print("INCORRECT! Correct answer is", (num_1 + num_2))
 
print ("Your score was", score,"/10")
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Put the variable `score` outside the loop, so it is not initialized back to `0` with each iteration.

Get the `if-else` conditions inside the `for-loop` to check for the current score every iteration:

```
import random
score = 0  # score var should be outside the loop
for x in range (0,10):
   num_1 = random.randint(1,10)
   num_2 = random.randint(1,10)
   ansstring = "What is {0} + {1}:".format(num_1,num_2)
   answer = int(input(ansstring))
   if answer == (num_1 + num_2):
       print("CORRECT!")
       score = score + 1
       print ("Score:", score)
   else:
      print("INCORRECT! Correct answer is", (num_1 + num_2))
   
print ("Your score was", score,"/10")
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, take `score` out of the for loop:

```
import random
score = 0
for x in range (0,10):
   num_1 = random.randint(1,10)
   num_2 = random.randint(1,10)
   ansstring = "What is {0} + {1}:".format(num_1,num_2)
   answer = int(input(ansstring))

   if answer == (num_1 + num_2):
      print("CORRECT!")
      score += 1
      print ("Score:",score)
   else:
      print("INCORRECT! Correct answer is", (num_1 + num_2))
       
print ("Your score was", score,"/10")
```

The reason yours didn't work is because, during each iteration, you are setting `score = 0` over and over.

Answer (score 0):

Things you have to change:

1. Score must be outside the `for loop` because you are giving it the value 0 each time.
2. You must increment the score when the answer is right.
3. Your if-else statements must be within the `for loop`

Here is how the code should look like:

```
import random

score = 0
for x in range (0,10):
   num_1 = random.randint(1,10)
   num_2 = random.randint(1,10)
   ansstring = "What is {0} + {1}:".format(num_1,num_2)
   answer = int(input(ansstring))
   if answer == (num_1 + num_2):
       print("CORRECT!")
       score = score + 1
       print ("Score:",score)

   else:
        print("INCORRECT! Correct answer is", (num_1 + num_2))
```

Comment: A small nitpick, but he already incremented the score if the answer was right. He just put if statements outside for loop.